# Exposing OData in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, salesforce, odata

I have looked at the lightning connect - which I was only recently informed of, and I like the look off it and I am planing to try and use it.

However I have run into an issue, I want to use a rails application to expose data as OData. I was wondering if anybody with experience would give be able to give me some advice on where to start.
Thank you.

Comment: How different is OData? We have a similar request to expose data as OData but there appears to be no pre-built libraries to handle the heavy lifting. I'm wondering if just accepting certain params in your API and delivering the response in JSON in a layout they are expecting is sufficient. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The answer seems to be that there is none, really. People seem to either not provide OData endpoints for their ruby/rails APIs, or maybe they just "wing it"... maybe we're thinking too complicated here, I mean OData is RESTful, rails is RESTful, JSON is well supported. Maybe it's perfectly fine to just define a few routes and be done with it.

https://github.com/lmcalpin/odata_server is a fork that has a commit at the end of 2015, at least. Still alpha and very, very small feature set, though.

@StormViper, did you find a solution meanwhile? I am looking at the same thing at the moment, and my searches only turned up client libraries for ruby, aside from that one. Even the API list on odata.org doesn't have anything.

Answer (score 1):

The official OData site has a list of [libraries](http://www.odata.org/libraries/), but there is currently nothing there for Ruby. There is an [OData server project](https://github.com/bwlang/odata_server) on Github, but it hasn't had an update for several years.